# How to convert Map[String,Any] to Map[String,Map[String ...] recursively?

Tags: scala

Based on this example:

```
val map:Map[String,Any]=Map("1"->Map("1.1"->Map("1.1.1"->"value")))
```

What it the transformation needed in the middle in order to used as follow:

```
println(map("1")("1.1")("1.1.1"))
```

Comment: Where does this map come from?  Why does it have to be using Any?  Once you have Any, it is difficult to impossible to get back to a proper type.  With this map always be nested 3 deep, or can it vary?  Do do what you want you'd need to iterate over the map, checking types and filtering out any elements that don't match the type you want, then apply a cast.

Comment: @puhlen Right. This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The answer to the question as asked would be `map.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Map[String,Map[String,String]]]]` but that's probably not what you're actually looking for.

Comment: The nested Maps can vary, so far I am using an implicit with m.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]]

Comment: @Lengoman My first two questions are the more important ones.  You should be trying to avoid using any in the first place.

Comment: The reason why is a Map[String,Any] is because is the result of transforming a json that can contain nested elements.

Comment: That's not really a good reason. You need a better representation of JSON (most of the JSON readers handle this better - are you using one or rolling your own?)